# Python Tkinter GUI does not open when the script is called by C# program

Tags: python, c#, tkinter

`

```
var psierror = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psierror.FileName = @"C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe";
        psierror.Arguments = $"\"{exception_case}\" \"{Image}\"";
        psierror.UseShellExecute = false;
        psierror.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psierror.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psierror.RedirectStandardError = true;

        var errors_again = "";
        var results_again = "";
        using (var process = Process.Start(psierror))
        {
            errors_again = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results_again = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(results_again);
    }
```

`
This is the C# segment that attempts to call the GUI but it seems like it just skips that program when ran. This code worked for calling a non-GUI python script so I just assumed it would work for this script as well. Any help is appreciated

What I want to happen is that the C# program calls the python script which starts the GUI to allow the user to make the selections. Afterwards, the value of the  selections are sent to the C# program to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with my python script and I also changed the CreateNoWindow to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).